# How to match up a User Profile with a file in their corresponding C:\User folder in a Powershell Script?

Tags: windows, powershell, user-profile

I am currently being tasked with deleting user profiles older than two weeks from several hundred machines on my domain.

Due to the tedious nature of the task, I decided to look into scripting to try and make the process easier. I am VERY new to PowerShell and after doing a lot of digging to find out how to tackle this, I came up with the following:

```
Get-CimInstance -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}| Remove-CimInstance
```

However, because of Windows updates and antivirus scans, I am unable to rely on the LastUseTime property referenced above. After more research, the only reliable timestamp I could find for when a user has last logged on to the machine is the last modified date of the IconCache.db file in their C:\Users folder.

My idea for the script would be something like this:

```
#for each user in C:Users (excluding system accounts)
#get the last modified date of their IconCache.db file,
#if the last modified date of their IconCache.db file is less than 30 days,
#find their corresponding user profile,
#delete the corresponding user profile,
```

and I have implemented the above idea as best I can as shown below

```
$Path = "C:\Users"
$UserFolders = $Path | GCI -Directory

ForEach ($User in $UserFolders)
{Get-ChildItem C:\Users\$User\AppData\Local\IconCache.db -Hidden 
 if ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
 {
 Get-CimInstance -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.LocalPath -eq (???))} | Remove-CimInstance
 }}
```

With this script, I am attempting to match each $User in the foreach loop with their corresponding User profile in the Win32_UserProfile class. However, I am unsure how I would match up the LocalPath property to each user in $Users. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [1] what is your actual, specific Question? ///// [2] on my system, the `ntuser.dat` file seems to be untouched by my anti-malware util. ///// [3] if you actual Question is how to  match the user account with a particular profile ... the user account name on my system is the last  part of the `.LocalPath` value.

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague. I am a complete novice at powershell and find it difficult to communicate ideas in a concise manner. My question is: in the line "Get-CimInstance -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.LocalPath -eq (???))}", what can I enter in the parenthesis to compare the LocalPath value from the CimInstance to the path in C:\users?

Comment: please take a look at my Answer. it think it covers what you are asking about - if not, ask me! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do what i think you want ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- grabs the local profiles into an array
  the `@()` wrapped around the call ensures you always get an array.
- the above was also filtered to exclude the `.Loaded` and `.Special` profiles
- defines the local user dirs to exclude
  you usually have a few that you want to keep. [*grin*]
- builds a regex OR from that collection
- grabs the dirs in `C:\Users` & excludes the "hands off!" items
- filters the CIM profile list against the local `Users` dirs
- displays the various values involved
- displays any CIM profile that matched ones in the local `c:\Users` dir

the code ...

```
$ProfileList = @((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile |
    Where-Object {
        -not $_.Special -and
        -not $_.Loaded
        }))

$ExcludedAccountDirs = @(
    'public'
    'default'
    )
$RegexEAD = $ExcludedAccountDirs -join '|'

$LocalUserDirList = @((Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Users' -Directory |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Name -notmatch $RegexEAD
        }).FullName)

$PL_in_LUDL = $ProfileList |
    Where-Object {
    $_.LocalPath -in $LocalUserDirList
    }

'=' * 30
$ProfileList.LocalPath
'=' * 30
$LocalUserDirList
'=' * 30
$PL_in_LUDL
```

output ...

```
==============================
C:\Users\AltUserName
==============================
C:\Users\MyUserName
C:\Users\AltUserName
==============================


AppDataRoaming                   : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Contacts                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Desktop                          : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Documents                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Downloads                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Favorites                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
HealthStatus                     : 3
LastAttemptedProfileDownloadTime : 
LastAttemptedProfileUploadTime   : 
LastBackgroundRegistryUploadTime : 
LastDownloadTime                 : 
LastUploadTime                   : 
LastUseTime                      : 2021-06-15 3:00:31 AM
Links                            : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Loaded                           : False
LocalPath                        : C:\Users\AltUserName
Music                            : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Pictures                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
RefCount                         : 
RoamingConfigured                : False
RoamingPath                      : 
RoamingPreference                : 
SavedGames                       : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Searches                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
SID                              : S-1-5-21-3587298852-2732022926-2745136909-1001
Special                          : False
StartMenu                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Status                           : 0
Videos                           : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
PSComputerName                   :
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! It is much appreciated and I thank you for taking the time out to help me. However, what I would like to do is a bit different. I would like to filter out and remove user profiles based on the last modified date of their C:\Users\InsertUsernameHere\AppData\Local\IconCache.db file

Comment: @JellyfishPirate - you said `what can I enter in the parenthesis to compare the LocalPath value from the CimInstance to the path in C:\users?`. i presumed that once you had that, you could check the date of the target file.